# GRASS init error: GRASS was not found in '/Applications/GRASS-7.2.app' (GISBASE), provider and plugin will not work

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, mac

I get this same error even though my GRASS app is in '/Applications/GRASS-7.2.app' has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Plugins / GRASS / GRASS options / General / custom / browse: then I choose '/Applications/GRASS-7.2.app'

Then in the modules tab I leave the default.

I have a MAC, everything updated, and QGIS is the most recent 2.18.14.

Comment: Which Mac OS, and which sources did you install from?